# Container extension "framework" is not registered

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I deployed my project based on Symfony4 on a server. 
When I run composer install on it, I have this error on cache:clear :

```
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In ContainerBuilder.php line 213:
!!
!!    Container extension "framework" is not registered
!!
!!
```

I checked and no file is missing. On my computer, I don't have this error and all is running well with the exact same code.

Composer.json :

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "blackknight467/star-rating-bundle": "2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1",
    "jmose/command-scheduler-bundle": "^2.0",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.1",
    "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~5.1",
    "setasign/fpdi": "1.6.*",
    "setasign/fpdi-tcpdf": "1.6.2",
    "spipu/html2pdf": "5.0.*",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "^4.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^4.0",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/form": "^4.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.1",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/translation": "^4.0",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0"
},
```

Comment: can you show your `composer.json`? Also, can you run the `cache:clear` locally?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25618 hope it helps

Comment: I added part of Composer.json to my question. I've already looked at this link but it doesn't help, I have symfony/console in my composer.json

Comment: What happens when you run `php bin/console cache:clear` locally?

Comment: try removing all the cache inside your var folder  (var/cache/*) manually and try it again

Comment: How does your `config/bundles.php` look like? Is the FrameworkBundle registered?

Comment: We are upgrading to symfony 5.4 and facing the same error. In the bundles.php, this line is already present but still getting the issue. Not sure what is being missed. When running php bin/console cache:clear getting error as below : "!! Container extension "framework" is not registered." Not sure what is being missed, any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

Check if framework extension is loaded in your `bundles.php`:

```
return [
  Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  ...
```

Comment: We are upgrading to symfony 5.4 and facing the same error. In the bundles.php, this line is already present but still getting the issue. Not sure what is being missed.
When running php bin/console cache:clear getting error as below :
"!!    Container extension "framework" is not registered." 
Not sure what is being missed, any ideas ?

Comment: did you try to physically remove `/var/cache` folder and re-run `cache:clear` command?

Comment: In my case the entry in bundles.php was restricted to the 'prod' environment. Changing it to 'all' worked.